# Add stats for hats

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2013

It would be nice to see stats for Winter Bash hats in a way similar to the stats on badges. For example, it would be nice to find out how many times a particular hat has been earned:

[image: Illustration]

It would be nice if `Earned ### times` in the picture above were a link leading to a list of users who earned that hat - again, in a way similar to searching users who earned a particular badge.

Comment: Fair request, but maybe disable the list for secret hats, it will make it too easy to figure how to get them having such a list. (Showing how many users earned them is fine :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's true. I am not sure if it would make it "too easy" to figure out, but it would certainly bring the complexity down a bit. Making secret badges easier to figure out may be a good thing, too, because it could contribute to their popularity.

Comment: I would *really* like to see the stats for the hats on a per-site basis.  For example, how many people got the "do a review" hat or "participate in the closing of a question" hat.

Comment: I have to disagree.  Hats are fun, but already with some hats we're seeing negative effects from gaming them (see the issues with the flag queue and excessive NotAnAnswer flagging).  Having more statistics may encourage that further, which is probably not a good thing.

Comment: @Joe Moderators have perfect tools for fixing the excessive "Not and answer" flagging, so I do not see it as a big issue (apart from increasing moderator's workload). Overall, I think the benefits far outweigh the costs here: some hats are deigned to encourage certain behavior patterns not typical on these sites (e.g. purposely "stealing" a check mark by posting a better answer) which improve the quality of Q&A. I think that knowing for sure or being able to guess what's required to earn a hat is a good thing overall.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight If that's the case, then announce what those requirements are.  I'm not sure what encouraging gaming is going to do other than encourage people to find ways to earn hats that might not be appropriate.