# Search For Hats

Tags: discussion, search, winter-bash-2013

Is there a way to search for hats? (For example, who has the most, how many of X hat has been collected etc)

Kind of like the badge statistics, but not that revealing to preserve the secrecy of secret hats.

Edit: if there is no such feature, maybe consider it for next year?

Comment: Nope, all we know about hats comes from the leaderboards and individual profiles.

Comment: You can check the [network wide leaderboard](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) to see how woefully inadequate we all are compared to Manishearth - a feature request has already been made for how many of each badge have been issued [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213004/add-stats-for-hats)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For who has the most, you can always check the [leaderboard](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard)

[image: current leaders]

Comment: This is exactly what I was wondering! Thank you

Comment: Well that's weird.. I'm not on the Stack Overflow leaderboard and I have 15 hats :(

Comment: @RUJordan - Keep in mind that the count for each exchange is only hats earned on that exchange. At present you have 14 hats on SO.

Comment: Disregard my ignorance. Thanks man, checkmark coming your way in like 10 minutes.

Comment: @RUJordan I see you - you're currently #118 on Stack Overflow in terms of hat abundance

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to search for the type of information you're after, but we do plan to provide highlights of that sort of thing in our blog post after the event ends.